# How to store multiple contact numbers per employee

Tags: sql-server

I want to add multiple values to a single record. For example `dbo.TblEmp`
has columns like `ID`, `Name`, & `ContactNo`, and a employee can have 2 or 3 contact numbers.

Like:

```
ID     Name      ContactNo
0001   John      914587962
                 997896547
```

Comment: Don't add multiple values to a single column, it breaks the first normal form of the database; read up on database normalization instead and learn to design your tables a better way. See this for an introduction: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dbms/database_normalization.htm

Comment: Also read this: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Answer (score 2):

You can create an additional table name EmployeeCommunication and using foreign keys you can define a relation with Employee in TblEmp to EmployeeCommunication table where ContactNo is stored